# MySQL import only if TWO VALUES don't repeat

Tags: mysql, insert, repeat

Let's say that you have a table:

```
Time Fish   Name

5    salmon John
9    whale  Michael
7    shark  Harry
```

And I want to insert a row. But I also want it NOT to insert it if TIME and FISH repeat.

So I can add `5 whale Unnamed`, I can add `9 salmon Michael`, but I can't add `5 salmon Michael`, I can't add `5 salmon John` and so on.

Is that possible?

Comment: make the time, fish both unique

Comment: Using  ^ advice. **[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/209a4/1/0)**

Comment: @AlaaM.Jaddou Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: @lad2025 Thank you for your quick response too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make both columns Unique. Run bellow Query

```
ALTER TABLE mytbl ADD UNIQUE (Time, Fish);
```

Answer (score 0):

While creating the table you can declare a composite primary key

> create table tablename (Time int,fish varchar(5), name varchar(10),primary key(Time,fish));
>   This will allow only unique pairs of time and fish